# How to import SQL file to MySQL database without phpMyAdmin

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin

I have a .sql file with a MySQL dump created with phpMyAdmin.

I want to import the .sql file to another database without phpMyAdmin access. I have the database credentials: name, username and password.

How can I import the .sql file?

The SQL file is:
http://pastebin.com/cVTZpiMu

Comment: Do you have FTP access? you can use Adminer as a single .php  to manage your MySQL DB as a nice webui - http://www.adminer.org/

Comment: How does your .sql file look like? Because sometimes the sql file will have all the necesary statements to import it

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sure, it's very easy. On the command line...

```
mysql -u<USERNAME> -p<PASSWORD> <DATABASE> < /path/to/my.sql
```

For example:

```
mysql -urjdown -pmypass mydatabase < /home/rjdown/my.sql
```

Comment: Can you help me, what if ths sql dump contains a CREATE database command? So how can I import without a pre-created database? I tried on my localhost with the "mysql -u root -p my.sql" command, but didn't work for me.

Answer (score 2):

From the command line:

```
mysql -u username -p password dbname < file.sql
```

Or if it's remote:

```
mysql -h hostname -u username -p password dbname < file.sql
```

Comment: The accepted answer doesn't have spaces after the `-u`, `-p` etc, which is just hideous. Yours is better. ;)

Comment: @Magicode bit of a late reply! but the mysql docs state "If you use the -p option, there must be no space between -p and the following password value. " - https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/user-names.html

Comment: Yes I think you're right. This probably doesn't even work. xD

Answer (score 0):

just run `mysql -u YOUR_USER -p DATABASE_NAME < dump.sql` and enter your password. Where:

- `YOUR_USER` - MySQL user name
- `DATABASE_NAME`- database name to which
  to install to

You will be prompted for password.

Do not provide your password directly in command because of security reasons.